# Git, how to combine multiple projects preserving history, without using sub-modules

Tags: git, version-control, merge, repository, project

We have few distinct maven projects under Git version control. Now, I would like to combine these projects as maven multi-module project under aggregate POM, and make a new repository for this multi-module project.

**However, I don't want to lose history of those aggregated projects.** I tried to init a new repository for the aggregate project, and clone the existing repositories under the working tree. However, these sub-repositories are implicitly regarded as git submodules, and I'm not a fan of git submodule API. I think it's too obscure for other developers too, complicating things too much without real need.

I would like to just merge the history from those repositories to new aggregate repository somehow. I don't want to sync with the original repositories after merging the history, but just version control everything under new aggregate repository without submodules. Still, I would like to checkout a specific commit for any merged repository.

Is this possible in Git?

Comment: Have you get the answer which help you solve the problem? If yes, you can mark it as answer. And it will also benefit others who have similar questions.

Answer (score 1):

1. Initialize a new repo.
2. Copy the files of the desired versions from all the several projects and combine them together. You could rearrange the directory structure if necessary. And make sure the files have expected contents.
3. Setup `.gitignore`, `.gitattribute`, etc. Add them all and make the first commit for the new repo.
4. Fetch the branches from the several projects and merge them all with the option `-s ours`. The `ours` strategy merges histories only without real contents.

**Example:**

Let's say we have RepoA, RepoB and RepoC, all having a branch `master`. We're going to merge the files of the newest versions of the three branches.

```
git init RepoABC
cd RepoABC
#copy the files all RepoA, RepoB, RepoC and rearrange the directory structure if necessary.
#add .gitignore, .gitattribute, etc if necessary.
git add .
git commit -m 'new root for combining RepoA RepoB and RepoC'
git fetch origin_repoa master:repoa_master
git fetch origin_repob master:repob_master
git fetch origin_repoc master:repoc_master
git merge repoa_master repob_master repoc_master -s ours -m 'Merge and preserve the histories of RepoA, RepoB and RepoC, with merge strategy "ours"'
```

Now we can focus on the new repo's branch and make new changes. The histories are reserved and we can look back upon them. We may encounter a small problem when we checkout an old commit for the first time, if the directory structure has been rearranged. The new folders and files will stay after the commit is checked out, as untracked files. `git clean -df` will skip them, so we have to `rm -rf` them once for all.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible in git.

Assume there are two repos/projects need to combine, and for each repo, there are different branches:

Repo1: `master` and `dev1`

Repo2: `master` and `dev2`

In a new repo, you can  combine the projects together with below commands:

```
git init
# make changes and commit on master branch if you want to combine the aggregated projects in non-master branch
git remote add repo1 <URL for repo1> -f
git remote add repo2 <URL for repo2> -f
git checkout -b repo1_master repo1/master
git checkout -b repo1_dev1 repo1/dev1
git checkout -b repo2_master repo2/master
git checkout -b repo2_dev2 repo2/dev2
```

Now all the branches in repo1 and repo2 are aggregated in the new created repo in branches: `repo1_master`, `repo1_dev1`, `repo2_master` and `repo2_dev2`. And if you don’t need to make/get changes from repo1 and repo2 any more, you can remove the remotes:

```
git remote rm repo1
git remote rm repo2
```